# Highcharts: Decide on charts placement after generation

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is there a possibility to place a **highcharts** chart after it has been generated?

The background is, that I have a dedicated container (i.e. a `<div>`-node) where the user shall select one of two possible charts. 
Therefore I want to generate two charts, where the user can switch back and forth from the one to the other.

As the two (or possibly even more charts) are quite big, I want to generate them once at the beginning.

All the examples and the documentation I have seen always build a highcharts chart beginning at the related `<div>`-node:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

Possibly, you can use `renderTo` to assign the chart otherwise:

```
var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

But: What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
// at first, define the chart (without assignement to a <div>):
var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]   // does not work without 'renderTo'
});

// Then, assign it to a <div>:
myChart.renderTo('container');  // does not work :-(
```

The only option I've found is to generate a new chart with `new Highcharts.Chart({...})`, but as the chart may be quite huge, the switching between them would take quite a long time, whereas the wanted chart is available in memory already...

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: In case when some of options are common, you can use extend / merge. http://jsfiddle.net/tkBQW/1/

Answer (score 1):

The `new Highcharts.Chart()` constructor takes in options, so you could define the options early, and then when you are ready to use them you set `renderTo` and create your Highcharts object.

For example ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/V83QD/)):

```
// Set options early
var options = {
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    chart: {
        renderTo: null
    },
    ...
};

// When you are ready
setTimeout(function() {
    options.chart.renderTo = 'container';
    new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used this variant as it turned out that even generating big charts are no real performance issue in case the related options (see your answer above) are build in advance (including data tables).